# Precompiled Azure Function StorageTableInput binding not working

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

I am trying to convert an Azure Function App into a precompiled version using the '*Publishing a .NET class library as a Function App*' [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/16/publishing-a-net-class-library-as-a-function-app/) from Donna Malayeri.

The timer trigger I use has an StorageTable input binding using a typed object. The object inherits from '*TableEntity*'. While the version in the portal does not have any issues, my precompiled version throws the following error:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.ScheduleTrigger'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: GenericArguments[0], 'MyScheduler.Schedule', on 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Tables.TableExtension+TableToIQueryableConverter`1[TElement]' violates the constraint of type 'TElement'. mscorlib: GenericArguments[0], 'MyScheduler.Schedule', on 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Tables.TableExtension+TableToIQueryableConverter`1[TElement]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TElement'.
```

The Azure Function code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

namespace MyScheduler
{
    public class ScheduleTrigger
    {

        public static void Run(TimerInfo scheduleTimer, Queryable<Schedule> schedulesTable, ICollector<Schedule> scheduleQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"Start processing at: {DateTime.Now}.");

            // processing code here...

            log.Info($"Finished processing at: {DateTime.Now}.");
        }
    }

    public class Schedule : TableEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastRunAt { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public string Endpoint { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The '*function.json*' file looks like this:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "..\\bin\\MyScheduler.dll",
  "entryPoint": "MyScheduler.ScheduleTrigger.Run",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "scheduleTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 * * * * *"
    },
    {
      "type": "table",
      "name": "schedulesTable",
      "tableName": "schedules",
      "partitionKey": "Schedules",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "queue",
      "name": "scheduleQueueItem",
      "queueName": "schedulesqueue",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": true
}
```

Comment: What version of the Storage SDK are you referencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. Make sure you're referencing the Azure Storage SDK 7.2.1 or lower (ideally, 7.2.1)
2. The latest model for pre-compiled functions, with full tooling/Visual Studio integration, is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs). Please consider switching to that.

Comment: I did see your other answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42284705/precompiled-azure-function-and-cloudtable-binding-output-doesnt-work but since that wasn' the exact same issue I didn't actually try that.

Comment: Also... that answers was from well over a year ago... you'd expect something like that to be solved by now

Comment: Glad this helped. Moving to a new version is not something that will be done in a minor version release, so this will not change in 1.x. The 2.0 preview uses the latest version and we intend to expose a mechanism to soften this limitation.