# Odd Conflict in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

I've got an odd issue with a function input binding using the Visual Studio tooling. I created a simple function that has a http trigger and an input binding for table storage:

```
  [FunctionName("Scaling")]
    public static HttpResponseMessage Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "HttpTriggerCSharp/name/{name}")]HttpRequestMessage req, string name, [Table("scalingdatawesteurope", Connection = "scalingdataStorage")]CloudTable scalingDataTable, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        var customerScaleData = GetScaleData(name, scalingDataTable);
        log.Info("Sub:" + customerScaleData.Subscription);
        // Fetching the name from the path parameter in the request URL
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
    }
```

This works fine, and retrieves the data I want. However, what I now want to do is use this data to then run some operations against other Azure resources using the ARM API. So I import the Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent package with Nuget to allow me to do this. As soon as I import this package and add it as dependency my function starts failing. If I remove it, it all works again.

```
[23/10/2017 12:23:14] A ScriptHost error has occurred
[23/10/2017 12:23:14] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Scaling.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Can't bind Table to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable'.
[23/10/2017 12:23:14] Error indexing method 'Scaling.Run'
[23/10/2017 12:23:14] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Scaling.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Can't bind Table to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable'.
[23/10/2017 12:23:14] No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(), etc.).
[23/10/2017 12:23:14] Job host started
[23/10/2017 12:23:14] The following 1 functions are in error:
[23/10/2017 12:23:14] Run: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Scaling.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Can't bind Table to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable'.
[23/10/2017 12:23:14]
[23/10/2017 12:23:14]
[23/10/2017 12:23:14] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F195573C'.
Debugger listening on [::]:5858
```

It seems like there is some sort of conflict here, but I am struggling to find it or fix it.

Comment: What version of the storage SDK are you using? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42284705/precompiled-azure-function-and-cloudtable-binding-output-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent` has dependency on `WindowsAzure.Storage` of version `8.1.4` while Functions runtime uses `7.2.1`.

You can read more about issues with version conflicts in Azure Functions in [this github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/992).

But the easiest fix might be not to use umbrella `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent` (and thus `ContainerInstance.Fluent`) but reference just the sub-libraries that you need explicitly.

UPDATE:

As you mention, you probably can't use sub-libraries because of `Authenticate` call from the parent lib.

The only workaround I found so far is to switch to beta version of 2.0 runtime, where `8.x` version of `WindowsAzure.Storage` is used.

Comment: So I can import Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent alone, which resolves a lot of my dependencies, but I have one issue left which is the Azure.Authenticate(credentials) part, which requires Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent. I can't find a way to import just that without getting all of the sub packages as well, which then breaks things.

Comment: I ended up giving up and just using the REST API, worked fine. Seems like this dependency issues is a fairly big problem for functions. Anyway, you had the right answer so thanks.